# How to apply Joins in Oracle to require result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Following 3  tables :

```
SHIFT_MASTER,PATTERN_MASTER,PATTERN_DETAILS
```

S_ID ,P_ID,P_D_ID are the priamry keys of SHIFT_MASTER,PATTERN_MASTER,PATTERN_DETAILS tables respectively.

```
SHIFT_MASTER

S_ID | S_NUMBER|   S_Name
---------------------------------     
1        A          MORNING
2        B          AFTERNOON
3        C          NIGHT

PATTERN_MASTER
P_ID   |  P_NAME
---------------- 
1        Pattern 1  
2        Pattern 2     

PATTERN_DETAILS
P_D_ID|P_ID |  S_ID| ...
---------------------    
1       1        1     
2       1        2     
3       1        3 
4       1        2     
5       1        1     
6       2        3 
7       2        2     
8       2        1     
9       2        3
```

I GOT OUTPUT AS

```
    P_ID |  S_ID
    1       1,2,3,2,1
    2       3,2,1,3
```

USING QUERY

```
SELECT PATTERN_DETAILS.P_ID "PATTERN",
   LISTAGG(PATTERN_DETAILS.S_ID, ', ')
 WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PATTERN_DETAILS.P_D_ID) "SHIFT"
  FROM PATTERN_DETAILS
  GROUP BY PATTERN_DETAILS.P_ID;
```

WHAT I WANT IS

```
P_NAME     | S_NUMBER
Pattern 1    A,B,C,B,A
Pattern 2    C,B,A,C
```

Any suggestion ??? Instead of P_ID i want to show pattern name and instead of shift id i want to show shift number .How to perform join operation along with listagg function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join all three tables to get this,

```
SELECT pm.p_name "P_NAME",
       listagg(sm.s_number, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY pd.p_d_id) "S_NUMBER"
  FROM pattern_master pm,
       pattern_details pd, 
       shift_master sm
 WHERE sm.s_id= pd.s_id 
   AND pm.p_id = pd.p_id
GROUP BY pm.p_name;
```